# Cinema Seating With Gaps

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Given and Array

```
**[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]**
```

of occupied and unoccupied seats, where 1 indicated occupied and 0 indicated unoccupied, we have return the maximum maximum number of people who can be seated  as long  as there is a gap  of **2 seats **between people.

I trid a sliding window approac but it didnt worked

`

```
// maxim seats question

// [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]

function cinSeating(array) {
  let seats = 0;

  for (let p1 = 0, p2 = 3; p1, p2 <= array.length; p1++, p2++) {
    if (array[p1] !== array[p2]) {
      seats++;
    }
  }
  return seats;
}

console.log(cinSeating([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]));
```

`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _"as long as there is a gap of **2 seats **between people"_

Comment: @ phuzi that means there should be a gap of two empty seats between occupied seats.

Comment: So, in your example (`[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]`), only the seats at the very ends would be bookable?

Comment: @phuzi - Yes it should return 2 as the number of seats available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using dynamic programming to solve this problem.

**Basic approach**:

- Parse through the array one by one recursively
- At every point, check if that seat can be filled in or not. At this point, you can take either one of the two options - YES or NO
- If YES - increment the total count and call the same function with the next index and incremented count
- If YES - call the same function with the next index and existing count
- Find out the max between the two calculations and return the answer

Code will look something like this:

```
function hasAPerson(array, index){
    // Utility function to encapsulate all the checks while checking the next index for possible vacant seat
    if(index >= array.length){
        return false;
    }
    
    else return array[index] === 1;
}

function cinSeating(array, existingNumber, leftIndex, index) {
  let newlyAdded = 0;

  if(index >= array.length){
      return existingNumber;
  }

  if(array[index] === 1){
      return cinSeating(array, existingNumber, index, index + 1);
  }
  
  let excludeCurrentSeat = currentValue = cinSeating(array, existingNumber, leftIndex, index + 1);
  
  let includeCurrentSeat = existingNumber;
  
  //Check if last leftIndex with 1 is beyond index-2
  if(leftIndex < index-2){
      
      let next = index+1;
      let nextToNext = next+1;
      
      //Check if next or next to next index has any 1
      if(!hasAPerson(array, next) && !hasAPerson(array, nextToNext)){
          includeCurrentSeat = cinSeating(array, existingNumber + 1, index, index+1);
      }
  }
  
  return Math.max(currentValue, includeCurrentSeat);
}
```

You can call the cinSeating function with the following arguments:

- input array
- existing number of people (seats already booked) - basically number of 1s in the array
- last left index that had 1. When we start we can pass -3 so that left check gets passed
- index to process

  **console.log(cinSeating([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 2, -3, 0));**

This is something that I wrote quickly to illustrate my approach. This code can definitely be optimised. Feel free to play around with it